# PYSpark JDBC JDBC Query failing with Oracle Database

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am running a query to fetch data in JSON format from the Oracle19C database and below is my query

```
select '{"JSON_FILENAME" : "'||ID||'_'||'CUSTOMER'||'_'||'PURCHASE'||'_'||'202403050000'||'.json",'||REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(TRAILING ']' FROM TRIM( LEADING '{' FROM TRIM(LEADING '[' FROM JSONOBJECT))),CHR(10),NULL),CHR(13),NULL),': null',': ""'),'##',NULL) FROM JSON_LANDING WHERE DECODE(ENTITYTYPE,'PUR','PURCHASE','CUST','CUSTOMER','COMM','COMMISSION','PYMNT', 'COMMISSION_PAYMENTS',ENTITYTYPE)='CUSTOMER' AND BATCHCYCLEDATE >=TO_TIMESTAMP( '2024-03-05 11:59:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') AND BATCHCYCLEDATE <=TO_TIMESTAMP( '2024-03-06 11:59:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') AND ID <> 981345
```

Below is my JDBC connection

```
extraction_df = spark.read.format("jdbc")\
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")\
    .option("url", jdbcUrl)\
    .option("user", jdbcUsername)\
    .option("password", jdbcPassword)\
    .option("fetchsize","10000")\
    .option("query",extraction_query)\
    .load()
```

When ever i pass the query in JDBC connection i am getting below error

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

I tried couple of things in one of the data bricks article mentioned it is due to a bug in spark and instead of query it should be table with query in double quotes i tried same it is also failing below is the article

https://kb.databricks.com/data-sources/query-option-not-work-oracle.html#problem-apache-spark-jdbc-datasource-query-option-doesnt-work-for-oracle-database

I changed query to below and tried too

```
select '{"JSON_FILENAME" : "'||ID||'_'||'CUSTOMER'||'_'||'PURCHASE'||'_'||'202403050000'||'.json",'||REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(TRAILING ']' FROM TRIM( LEADING '{' FROM TRIM(LEADING '[' FROM JSONOBJECT))),CHR(10),NULL),CHR(13),NULL),': null',': ""'),'##',NULL) (SELECT * FROM JSON_LANDING WHERE DECODE(ENTITYTYPE,'PUR','PURCHASE','CUST','CUSTOMER','COMM','COMMISSION','PYMNT', 'COMMISSION_PAYMENTS',ENTITYTYPE)='CUSTOMER' AND BATCHCYCLEDATE >=TO_TIMESTAMP( '2024-03-05 11:59:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') AND BATCHCYCLEDATE <=TO_TIMESTAMP( '2024-03-06 11:59:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') AND ID <> 981345)
```

This also giving error

When i try to do dataframe explain to see the query sending to server i found the Spark making change to complete query as part of optimization and it is sending below query

```
extraction_df.explain(True)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
Relation ['{"JSON_FILENAME":"'||ID||'_'||'CUSTOMER'||'_'||'PURCHASE'||'_'||'202403050000'||'.JSON",'||REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(TRAILING']'FROMTRIM(LEADING'{'FROMTRIM(LEADING'['FROMJSONOBJECT))),CHR(10),NULL),CHR(13),NULL),':NULL',':""'),'##',NULL)#0] JDBCRelation((select '{"JSON_FILENAME" : "'||ID||'_'||'CUSTOMER'||'_'||'PURCHASE'||'_'||'202403050000'||'.json",'|| REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(TRAILING ']' FROM TRIM( LEADING '{' FROM TRIM(LEADING '[' FROM JSONOBJECT))),CHR(10),NULL),CHR(13),NULL),': null',': ""'),'##',NULL) FROM JSON_LANDING WHERE DECODE(ENTITYTYPE,'PUR','PURCHASE','CUST','CUSTOMER','COMM','COMMISSION','PYMNT', 'COMMISSION_PAYMENTS',ENTITYTYPE)='PURCHASE' AND BATCHCYCLEDATE >=TO_TIMESTAMP( '2024-03-05 11:59:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') AND BATCHCYCLEDATE <=TO_TIMESTAMP( '2024-03-06 11:59:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') AND ID <> 981345) SPARK_GEN_SUBQ_0) [numPartitions=1]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
'{"JSON_FILENAME":"'||ID||'_'||'CUSTOMER'||'_'||'PURCHASE'||'_'||'202403050000'||'.JSON",'||REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(TRAILING']'FROMTRIM(LEADING'{'FROMTRIM(LEADING'['FROMJSONOBJECT))),CHR(10),NULL),CHR(13),NULL),':NULL',':""'),'##',NULL): string
Relation ['{"JSON_FILENAME":"'||ID||'_'||'CUSTOMER'||'_'||'PURCHASE'||'_'||'202403050000'||'.JSON",'||REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(TRAILING']'FROMTRIM(LEADING'{'FROMTRIM(LEADING'['FROMJSONOBJECT))),CHR(10),NULL),CHR(13),NULL),':NULL',':""'),'##',NULL)#0] JDBCRelation((select '{"JSON_FILENAME" : "'||ID||'_'||'CUSTOMER'||'_'||'PURCHASE'||'_'||'202403050000'||'.json",'|| REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(TRAILING ']' FROM TRIM( LEADING '{' FROM TRIM(LEADING '[' FROM JSONOBJECT))),CHR(10),NULL),CHR(13),NULL),': null',': ""'),'##',NULL) FROM JSON_LANDING WHERE DECODE(ENTITYTYPE,'PUR','PURCHASE','CUST','CUSTOMER','COMM','COMMISSION','PYMNT', 'COMMISSION_PAYMENTS',ENTITYTYPE)='PURCHASE' AND BATCHCYCLEDATE >=TO_TIMESTAMP( '2024-03-05 11:59:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') AND BATCHCYCLEDATE <=TO_TIMESTAMP( '2024-03-06 11:59:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') AND ID <> 981345) SPARK_GEN_SUBQ_0) [numPartitions=1]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Relation ['{"JSON_FILENAME":"'||ID||'_'||'CUSTOMER'||'_'||'PURCHASE'||'_'||'202403050000'||'.JSON",'||REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(TRAILING']'FROMTRIM(LEADING'{'FROMTRIM(LEADING'['FROMJSONOBJECT))),CHR(10),NULL),CHR(13),NULL),':NULL',':""'),'##',NULL)#0] JDBCRelation((select '{"JSON_FILENAME" : "'||ID||'_'||'CUSTOMER'||'_'||'PURCHASE'||'_'||'202403050000'||'.json",'|| REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(TRAILING ']' FROM TRIM( LEADING '{' FROM TRIM(LEADING '[' FROM JSONOBJECT))),CHR(10),NULL),CHR(13),NULL),': null',': ""'),'##',NULL) FROM JSON_LANDING WHERE DECODE(ENTITYTYPE,'PUR','PURCHASE','CUST','CUSTOMER','COMM','COMMISSION','PYMNT', 'COMMISSION_PAYMENTS',ENTITYTYPE)='PURCHASE' AND BATCHCYCLEDATE >=TO_TIMESTAMP( '2024-03-05 11:59:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') AND BATCHCYCLEDATE <=TO_TIMESTAMP( '2024-03-06 11:59:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') AND ID <> 981345) SPARK_GEN_SUBQ_0) [numPartitions=1]

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Scan JDBCRelation((select '{"JSON_FILENAME" : "'||ID||'_'||'CUSTOMER'||'_'||'PURCHASE'||'_'||'202403050000'||'.json",'|| REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(TRAILING ']' FROM TRIM( LEADING '{' FROM TRIM(LEADING '[' FROM JSONOBJECT))),CHR(10),NULL),CHR(13),NULL),': null',': ""'),'##',NULL) FROM JSON_LANDING WHERE DECODE(ENTITYTYPE,'PUR','PURCHASE','CUST','CUSTOMER','COMM','COMMISSION','PYMNT', 'COMMISSION_PAYMENTS',ENTITYTYPE)='PURCHASE' AND BATCHCYCLEDATE >=TO_TIMESTAMP( '2024-03-05 11:59:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') AND BATCHCYCLEDATE <=TO_TIMESTAMP( '2024-03-06 11:59:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') AND ID <> 981345) SPARK_GEN_SUBQ_0) [numPartitions=1] ['{"JSON_FILENAME":"'||ID||'_'||'CUSTOMER'||'_'||'PURCHASE'||'_'||'202403050000'||'.JSON",'||REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(TRAILING']'FROMTRIM(LEADING'{'FROMTRIM(LEADING'['FROMJSONOBJECT))),CHR(10),NULL),CHR(13),NULL),':NULL',':""'),'##',NULL)#0] PushedAggregates: [], PushedFilters: [], PushedGroupby: [], ReadSchema: struct<'{"JSON_FILENAME":"'||ID||'_'||'CUSTOMER'||'_'||'PURCHASE'||'_'||'202403050000'||'.JSON",'||REPLA...
```

I suspect it is sending only the below part to the oracle database

```
bound method DataFrame.explain of DataFrame['{"JSON_FILENAME":"'||ID||'_'||'APS'||'_'||'POLICY'||'_'||'202403050000'||'.JSON",'||REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(TRAILING']'FROMTRIM(LEADING'{'FROMTRIM(LEADING'['FROMJSONOBJECT))),CHR(10),NULL),CHR(13),NULL),':NULL',':""'),'##',NULL): string]>
```